# SwiftUI Chart Overlay Object Positioning Not Correct

Tags: ios, swiftui, charts

I'm struggling with an overlay on a bar chart where the user can tap and drag
to get more information.

I used the same code (modified for the data type) on a previous app and it worked
perfectly. That makes me think that something in the framework changed with xcode 14.3.

The user should be able to tap and drag and see data for the bars - in this case simply
the year and a number.

However, when the chart is tapped here, the rectangle pointer is incorrectly placed and
but the data reported in the bubble is correct. In this case the pointer is one bar off but that
is a conincidence - if there were more data points the error would be more than one
bar off.

And also strange, if I comment out the offset for the rectangle pointer, it disappears.
If I set the offset to 0.0 it disappears. In both of these cases, the tap point
on a device or the cursor in the simulator still show the correct data.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showSelectionBar = false
    @State private var offsetX: Double = 0.0
    @State private var offsetY = 0.0

    @State private var thisSelectedYear = "2010"
    @State private var selectedYearGeneration: Double = 0.0

    let tempColors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .orange, .red]

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Some Data")
                .font(.title2)
            GroupBox {
                Chart(Datum.exampleData) { item in
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Year", String(item.period)),
                        y: .value("Generation", (item.generation))
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", item.type))
                }
            }//group box
            .frame(height: 500)
            .padding()
            .chartYScale(domain: 0...40)
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(
                    values: stride(
                        from: 0,
                        to: 50,
                        by: 10).map { $0 }
                )
            }//chart y axis
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(position: .bottom, values: .automatic) { value in
                    if ((value.index % 2) != 0) {
                        AxisValueLabel() {
                            if let strValue = value.as(String.self) {
                                Text(strValue)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 45))
                                    .padding(.top)
                            }//if let value as string
                        }//axis value label
                    }//if
                }//axis marks
            }//chart x axis
            .chartLegend(spacing: 20)
        
            .chartOverlay { pr in
                GeometryReader { geoProxy in
                
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.orange.gradient)
                        .frame(width: 2, height: geoProxy.size.height * 0.95)
                        .opacity(showSelectionBar ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                    //this is the line
                        .offset(x: offsetX)
                    //above is the line
                    Capsule()
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue.gradient)
                        .frame(width: 160, height: 80)
                        .overlay {
                            VStack {
                                Text(thisSelectedYear)
                                Text("Generation: \(selectedYearGeneration, specifier: "%.0f")")
                            }
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        }
                        .opacity(showSelectionBar ? 1.0 : 0)
                        .offset(x: offsetX - 50, y: offsetY - 100)
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle()).gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            if !showSelectionBar {
                                showSelectionBar = true
                            }
                            let origin = geoProxy[pr.plotAreaFrame].origin
                            let location = CGPoint(
                                x: value.location.x - origin.x,
                                y: value.location.y - origin.y
                            )
                            print(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
                            print("location: \(location.x)")
                            offsetX = location.x
                            offsetY = location.y
                        
                            let (year, _) = pr.value(at: location, as: (String, Double).self) ?? ("-", 0)
                            print("year is" , year)
                        
                            thisSelectedYear = year
                        
                            let selectedDatum: Datum = Datum.exampleData.first(where: {
                                $0.period == Int(thisSelectedYear)
                            }) ?? Datum.exampleData[0]
                        
                            selectedYearGeneration = selectedDatum.generation
                        
                        }//on changed
                        .onEnded{ _ in
                            showSelectionBar = false
                        })//gesture
                }//geo proxy
            }//overlay
        
            Spacer()
        }//v
    }//body
}//struct



// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let period: Int
    let type: String
    let generation: Double

    static let exampleData: [Datum] = [
        Datum(period: 2001, type: "A", generation: 10.0),
        Datum(period: 2002, type: "A", generation: 15.0),
        Datum(period: 2003, type: "A", generation: 5.0),
        Datum(period: 2003, type: "B", generation: 10.0),
        Datum(period: 2003, type: "C", generation: 10.0),
        Datum(period: 2004, type: "A", generation: 25.0),
        Datum(period: 2005, type: "A", generation: 30.0),
        Datum(period: 2006, type: "A", generation: 27.0),
        Datum(period: 2007, type: "A", generation: 22.0),
        Datum(period: 2007, type: "B", generation: 12.0),
        Datum(period: 2008, type: "A", generation: 17.0),
        Datum(period: 2008, type: "B", generation: 12.0),
        Datum(period: 2009, type: "A", generation: 12.0),
        Datum(period: 2010, type: "A", generation: 7.0)
    ]

}//struct
```

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14.3, iOS 16.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with views in SwiftUI that aren't doing what they should be doing, my first go to device is really low tech. Add a color to things to see how they are laying out. What you don't see in code, becomes glaringly obvious when colored.

On the `Rectangle()` that you are measuring your drag on, I changed the `.clear` to `.purple.opacity(0.4)`, and this is what I see:

[image: Image of a chart with a transparent purple overlay that is larger than the chart.]

The issue kind of jumps out at you. You have the `Chart` in a `GroupBox` with a `.frame(height: 500)` and then `.padding()` around it. The `Rectangle()` is outside of those modifiers, and therefore not constrained by them, so it ends up as the total size including the padding, whereas the `GroupBox` has an interior padding so that it acts as a frame, and then the `.padding()` adds a greater difference. So, you were correct in that it had nothing to do with the size of the bars, rather it was the fact that the `Rectangle()` and `Chart()` were not the same size.

To fix it, simply move the `.chartOverlay()`, and for uniformity sake, the rest of the chart modifiers indie of the GroupBox. See the code below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSelectionBar = false
    @State private var offsetX: Double = 0.0
    @State private var offsetY = 0.0

    @State private var thisSelectedYear = "2010"
    @State private var selectedYearGeneration: Double = 0.0

    let tempColors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .orange, .red]

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Some Data")
                .font(.title2)
            GroupBox {
                Chart(Datum.exampleData) { item in
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Year", String(item.period)),
                        y: .value("Generation", (item.generation))
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", item.type))
                }
                .chartYScale(domain: 0...40)
                .chartYAxis {
                    AxisMarks(
                        values: stride(
                            from: 0,
                            to: 50,
                            by: 10).map { $0 }
                    )
                }//chart y axis
                .chartXAxis {
                    AxisMarks(position: .bottom, values: .automatic) { value in
                        if ((value.index % 2) != 0) {
                            AxisValueLabel() {
                                if let strValue = value.as(String.self) {
                                    Text(strValue)
                                        .font(.caption)
                                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 45))
                                        .padding(.top)
                                }//if let value as string
                            }//axis value label
                        }//if
                    }//axis marks
                }//chart x axis
                .chartLegend(spacing: 20)
            
                .chartOverlay { pr in
                    GeometryReader { geoProxy in
                    
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.orange.gradient)
                            .frame(width: 2, height: geoProxy.size.height * 0.95)
                            .opacity(showSelectionBar ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                        //this is the line
                            .offset(x: offsetX)
                        //above is the line
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue.gradient)
                            .frame(width: 160, height: 80)
                            .overlay {
                                VStack {
                                    Text(thisSelectedYear)
                                    Text("Generation: \(selectedYearGeneration, specifier: "%.0f")")
                                }
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }
                            .opacity(showSelectionBar ? 1.0 : 0)
                            .offset(x: offsetX - 50, y: offsetY - 100)
                        Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle()).gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                if !showSelectionBar {
                                    showSelectionBar = true
                                }
                                let origin = geoProxy[pr.plotAreaFrame].origin
                                let location = CGPoint(
                                    x: value.location.x - origin.x,
                                    y: value.location.y - origin.y
                                )
                                print(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
                                print("location: \(location.x)")
                                offsetX = location.x
                                offsetY = location.y
                            
                                let (year, _) = pr.value(at: location, as: (String, Double).self) ?? ("-", 0)
                                print("year is" , year)
                            
                                thisSelectedYear = year
                            
                                let selectedDatum: Datum = Datum.exampleData.first(where: {
                                    $0.period == Int(thisSelectedYear)
                                }) ?? Datum.exampleData[0]
                            
                                selectedYearGeneration = selectedDatum.generation
                            
                            }//on changed
                            .onEnded{ _ in
                                showSelectionBar = false
                            })//gesture
                    }//geo proxy
                }//overlay
            }//group box
            .frame(height: 500)
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }//v
    }//body
}//struct
```

Comment: Wow. Fantastic. This works. I love the debug technique. I will use that.